# How do I use SQL to Drop a Column from a MS ACCESS Database if that column is a replication ID?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I had a notion to use a database column of type replication ID, but have since changed my approach and want to use this column for another purpose.

However, I'm unable to use SQL to drop the column to remove it from my database.

My SQL is:

```
ALTER TABLE foo_bar DROP COLUMN theFoo;
```

However, I get a "syntax error" and I'm assuming this has something to do with this column being a replication ID.

I'd rather not download the file and edit it directly using the MS Access application, but not sure if that's my only recourse.

Thanks so much in advance.

Regards,

Kris

Comment: It is a while since I used replication, but I seem to remember that the easiest thing to do was to copy all the other columns to a new table. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the database in a command shell, [Michael Kaplan's Replication System Removal Fields utility](http://www.trigeminal.com/lang/1033/utility.asp?ItemID=11) should do the trick. However, I've found that in some circumstances, it's unable to do the job. Also note that the utility will only work with a Jet 4 format database (MDB), not ACE format (ACCDB).

If all else fails, you can recreate the table structure and append the existing data to it. That can get messy if you have referential integrity defined, though, but it will get the job done, and likely most of it is scriptable (if not all possible using just DDL).

Comment: I ended up doing just this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that may help you, I had a similar idea but when browsing the web found this

[AccessMonster - Replication-ID-Field-size](http://www.accessmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/access/102038/Replication-ID-Field-size)

EDIT: Well I don't have much time but what I was thinking of first was if you could alter the column to make it different (not a replication ID) and then drop it. (two separate actions). But I have not tested this.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the link.  Unfortunately, I'm getting stuck on the delete part.  I just want the column (field) to go away but it won't let me delete it.